# Why difference LayoutInflater cause difference SearchView Icon

Tags: java, android

Hello every Android geek, i has using LayoutInflater to customer My Android ActionBar.

but i  found that  difference LayoutInflater will cause generate difference SearchView Icon

This is my Difference LayoutInflater  and capture image

```
LayoutInflater mInflater1 =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//You can change mInflater1 =LayoutInflater.from(this); is a same result

LayoutInflater mInflater2 =LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
```

[image: This is mInflater1 Result]

[image: This is mInflater2 Result]

My Question is Why difference LayoutInflater cause difference SearchView Icon ?

Comment: Is it in the same OS version??

Comment: Yes is same OS , My Android Version is 4.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its that the context determines from where(theme) the icons are created. I guess your OS and the app has different themes
Read more here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

`The Context in which this LayoutInflater will create its Views; most importantly, this supplies the theme from which the default values for their attributes are retrieved.`

Comment: Thanks,i think it's get  difference themes Icons , is useful for me :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the second example (which I believe correlates to the first picture), you are using an Application Context to inflate Views instead of an Activity Context.

The framework does a lot of work to ensure that an Activity's Context is correctly configured with the correct screen density, theme, and other such information. An Application is not expected to ever need to worry about displaying content, so it is not configured to do so.

Do not use an Application context to inflate Views or obtain resources. Use an Activity context.